# Why is $_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO'] missing?

Tags: php, apache

`PUBLIC_ROOT/uploads/test.php` contains the following script and is accessed by https://example.com/updates/test.php/some/stuff?foo=bar

```
<?php

echo('PATH_INFO: '.($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']??'UNSET').PHP_EOL);
echo('ORIG_PATH_INFO: '.($_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO']??'UNSET').PHP_EOL);
```

The output is:

```
PATH_INFO: /some/stuff
ORIG_PATH_INFO: UNSET
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php states:

```
'ORIG_PATH_INFO'
Original version of 'PATH_INFO' before processed by PHP.
```

Why is $_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO'] not set?  What should the value be?  What can I do to configure my server to include it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in the question

```
'ORIG_PATH_INFO'
Original version of 'PATH_INFO' before processed by PHP.
```

Your server will include `$_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO']` If PHP made any changes to the original `PATH_INFO` via htaccess or mod_rewrite so for example if you rewrite everything after / to go to index.php/ (with htaccess: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]`) and you go to https://example.com/whatever
 `$_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO']` will be set to `/whatever` since this was the original path

Comment: Thank you Moses,  Couldn't find much documentation.  May I ask where you learned this?

Comment: Some hints here and there, (and some testing on my own)